# Script is not working in a modal window

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why this script is not working in a modal window (PrettyPhoto)? I tried

```
jQuery(document.body).ready(function(){
```

instead of

```
$(function() {
```

but the same result: script is working on normal webpage but not in modal windows.

When I select "New group" in drop-down menu, the script must display "tipoa" textfield which is hidden. In a modal window this field is not hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".forms").hide();
$("#typeg").change(function() {
switch($(this).val()){
case "new":
$(".forms").hide().parent().find("#form6").show();
break;
default: 
$(".forms").hide().parent().find("#form1").show();
break;
}
});
});
</script>

<form id="send" name="send">
Group:<br />
<select name="typeg" id="typeg">
<option value="29">Existing1</option>
<option value="30">Existing2</option>
<option value="new">New</option>
</select>
<div id="form1" class="forms"></div>
<div id="form6" class="forms">New group:<br /><input type="text" name="tipoa"/></div>
<input class="poga" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" /></form>
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: When I select "New group" in drop-down menu, the script must display "tipoa" textfield which is hidden. In modal window this field is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document.body).on('change','#typeg',function() {
var selected = $(this).val();
if(selected == 'new'){
$('#form6').show();
} else{ $('#form6').hide();}
});
```

and css:

```
#form6{display:none;}
```